# Help with diffs - Neither WebSVN or OpenGrok are diffing

Tags: diff, svn

I'm having issues which may or may not be related (excuse the vagueness).

In Web SVN, I can't select multiple revisions and compare - when I hit compare, I get a page with nothing on it other than showing the revisions. However, I can select compare previous at the top which will do a diff of the two most recent commits.

With OpenGrok, I get the history built fine from subversion, but when I click on history and then a revision, or try to compare revisions, it just sits there and doesn't do anything (i.e. I have had the Chrome spinning animation happening for >= 30min now).

I couldn't find out where OpenGrok logs or how to turn on logging, so excuse my ignorance there.

Any suggestions? It's not critical but it would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line tools? It sounds like your web services are mis-configured, but debugging them might take quite a lot of your time. From the command line you can diff any version to any version in a few seconds.

Comment: Yeah I know that Caleb, thanks for the help but I want to do it through the web interface. I can also diff in TortoiseSVN, but it'd be handy particularly for non-devs to be able to diff through the web ui.

Comment: Well then you'll need to start debugging the tool chain. Start with your web server logs and any logs specific to those web apps.